# Code First Migration on Production

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I am working with EF Code First Migration and before I push to the production, I created the InitialCreate file from scratch and then set the AutomaticMigrationsEnabled flag to 'False'. Then inside my web.config file, I defined my Db Initialization  strategy to 'MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion'..Then I simply deployed my website into production, so far things seems to work fine.

Now, let say I If add new field into of Entity class and push this change into production, it will try to migrate db to latest version and it fail with the error information :

**Unable to update database to match the current model because there are pending changes and automatic migration is disabled. Either write the pending model changes to a code-based migration or enable automatic migration. Set DbMigrationsConfiguration.AutomaticMigrationsEnabled to true to enable automatic migration.**

What I would need to do in this situation? Do I need to set the AutomaticMigrationsEnabled flag to True, or something else which would be suitable for production?

Thanks

Best Regards,
Ammar

Comment: Did you add the migration after you updated the Entity?

Comment: Do I need to explicitly update the migration by running the command add-migration? Wouldn't EF do by itself?

Comment: Yes, you need to do that since you turned off Automatic Migrations. That's what "Either write the pending model changes to a code-based migration" this line is telling you to do. When you deploy the app, the migration gets applied on the first call to the database and you'll see a new entry in the migrations table. Try it in a lower environment first if you want to see how it works.

Comment: Do I need to delete the previously create InitialCreate.cs before running the Add-migration command or it can be update by any other command?

Comment: You don't need to delete it.

Comment: So each time when my model change and I would like to push on production I will have to run add migration command to update the class.. And it will keep adding files in Migration directory, Is there a way I will have a single InitialCreate.cs file with all the new model changes including the initial one?

Comment: No, keep each group of changes in their own migration. That way, you can revert them if needed. See this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx#specific